# Automatic installation of clickhouse via script, how to answer the question about the default password

Tags: python, linux, bash, debian, clickhouse

I have a question:
I need to install clickhouse-server generic and client. I need to add this to my autoinstall script,
The problem is that during the installation of the package it asks for "Enter the default password", I just need to specify "enter" it blank, how do I auto-reply. one must first expect and include a separate file with the installer.
Maybe someone else has a solution?

I used expect, But it's rather inconvenient as it seems to me, I have to create a separate file so that it reads the execution of my script

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clickhouse respects `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/explain-debian_frontend-apt-get-variable-for-ubuntu-debian/

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install ....
```

Comment: Here is what worked for me: `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y clickhouse-server clickhouse-client`. Putting the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` before `sudo` did not work.